# How to see tags in a Powerpoint presentation

Tags: .net-core, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, syncfusion

I am working for an office-add-in for PowerPoint. I need to assign some unique identifier to my files, so that files can be identified in any dot net application. I did similar work for Word using custom properties. But for PowerPoint there is no way to read/ write custom property using office.js.
The only way I found using tags:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/tagging-presentations-slides-shapes

but when I add tags to the presentation, I am not able to see those tags in presentation directly, I am able to read/ write through code only. Also I am not getting a way to read these tags from dot net application.

Any help will be great.

I am storing my files to azure blob. And reading files in my dot net core application to identify whether it has been saved from an office-add in or not. I am using syncfusion library in dot net core application to work with files.

Comment: There's no user interface for adding/editing/removing tags; it can only be done through code (one of the things that makes tags so useful; end users can't meddle with them).  And ... "Also I am not getting a way to read these tags from dot net application."  What have you tried, and in which dot net language?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open a PPT file and add a few tags "wwwww", "yyyyy", "zzzzz".
2. Close and save the file.
3. Add ".zip" onto the end of the filename.
4. Use any unzipper program to unzip the file.
5. Search the folder of unzipped files for "wwwww", "yyyyy", "zzzzz".
6. This should tell you where/how tags are stored in the OOXML.
7. Your .NET app should be able to use the [OOXML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) to read the tags of a PPT file.

Answer (score 0):

At present, Syncfusion Presentation library do not have support to read and edit the tags of PowerPoint elements. Please track the status of this feature from below link,
https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/1800/create-and-edit-tags-for-powerpoint-elements

However, kindly try the below suggested workaround solutions to achieve your requirement,

1. **Using Shape.Name property:**

   - Add a shape with unique name while generating a document from Office-Addin. You can use [Shape.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.shape?view=powerpoint-js-preview#powerpoint-powerpoint-shape-name-member) property for this.
   - In .NET Core application, identify the corresponding shape by using [Shape.ShapeName](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/file-formats/Syncfusion.Presentation.ISlideItem.html#Syncfusion_Presentation_ISlideItem_ShapeName) property of Syncfusion Presentation library and decide whether its generated by Office-Addin or not. You can refer below UG documentation for more details,
     https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/presentation/working-with-shapes#specifying-shape-properties
2. **Using custom meta-data on Presentation:**

   - PowerPoint [Javascript API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/tagging-presentations-slides-shapes) states that, when we apply the tags for Presentation object it’s maintained as a custom property of PowerPoint document.
     [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3qG.png)
   - If so, you can able to iterate the custom property of PowerPoint document using [Presentation.CustomDocumentProperties](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/file-formats/Syncfusion.Presentation.IPresentation.html#Syncfusion_Presentation_IPresentation_CustomDocumentProperties) API of Syncfusion Presentation library. You can refer below UG documentation for more details,
     https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/presentation/working-with-powerpoint-presentation#adding-custom-document-properties

***Note: This update is from Syncfusion team***

Comment: Tags are *not* part of the Presentation.CustomDocumentProperties collection. The documentation you referred to says "When applied to a presentation, a tag is effectively a custom property in the presentation document (similar to a CustomProperty in Word)."  The key here is "similar to".  Not equal to.  But that's still a useful link, as it gives a JS example of creating tags.

Comment: These updates looks good but these are work-around. If I go ahead with 1st approach, then challenge is, if ever any one delete slide and add new slides in the PPT, shape will be no more and document tracking will be lost.
In the 2nd approach, I already tried but Tags work like CustomProperty in office.js but not exactly. Syncfusion library can iterate over custom property only and those are visible in Info section of PPT.
What I am trying is to use OpenXML to read and write tags on server side, will update once I am done.

Comment: The tags will be listed in files named e.g. tag1.xml, tag2.xml etc in the ppt\tags folder of a presentation file.  ppt\presentation\presentation.xml.rels will reveal the IDs that match presentation level tags to the correct tagX.xml file. \ppt\slides\_rels maps the ids of tags on slides to the proper tagX.xml file. The individual slide xml files in ppt\slides will have e.g. "<p:tags r:id="rId2"/>" as part of shape descriptions; these point to shape-level tags.